# Play audio stream with JavaFX

Tags: java, audio, javafx, javasound

I'm trying to make simple audio player with JavaFX Mediaplayer component. All local files are fine but i want also implement internet radio.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        new JFXPanel(); //init jfx library
        String u = "http://91.121.164.186:8050";
        Media m=null;
        try {
            m = new Media(u);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(m);
        System.out.println("play");
        player.play();
        player.setVolume(new Double(1));

    }
```

When I run it like this there is no errors but there is no audio. What's wrong ? What are other posibilities to play radio stream in Java ?

Answer (score 1):

In your current example I can see two errors,

1. You are trying to run a JAVAFX component on a non-Javafx thread, which will result in error. Try running your program inside the `start method`. Please go through [How to use JavaFX MediaPlayer correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490064/how-to-use-javafx-mediaplayer-correctly/22497685#22497685)
2. The URL you are trying to access must be a `Media Compoenent`

Try going through this extremely great example on Javafx Media

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/EmbeddedMediaPlayer.zip

N.B. The example has lot more data than your require, but its a great example !

Comment: As i said it's working with local files. The url is from .pls file so it should be good. How to convert it to media component ?

Comment: You can use the media types specified here as a direct media to the MediaPlayer http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html#SupportedMediaTypes

Answer (score 0):

`"http://91.121.164.186:8050"` is a website, (HTML document), not a audio file.  You need to download an audio file, something that the player knows what to do with.