# JavaFX - Playing an mp3

Tags: java, audio, javafx, mp3, media

```
package musictesting;
import java.io.File;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer; 
import javafx.scene.media.Media; 

public class playsound { 

    public static void testsound(){

       String musicFileName = "ROQUE.mp3"; 
       Media sound = new Media(new File(musicFileName).toURI().toString());
       Media song = new Media(Paths.get(musicFileName).toUri().toString());
       MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);
       mediaPlayer.play();
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
       testsound();
    }
```

}

For a group assignment I've been deligated to make the music that plays for a game developed in Java, I've been looking at some ways to play audio files and it seems like `JavaFX` is the way to go. I just wanted to run like a simple test player but I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" MediaException: MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE : C:\Users\Dylan\Documents\stuffinaround\musictesting\ROQUE.mp3 (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at musictesting.playsound.testsound(playsound.java:13)
    at musictesting.playsound.main(playsound.java:19)
```

The file ROQUE.mp3 is in my `source/bin` folders.

I've tried different code people have posted online, this seems pretty straight ahead. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Compare the URI you create with the physical location.

Comment: It seems to be correct. Could anything else cause this error?

Comment: you can fetch the ressources with: `this.getClass().getResource("/bin/ROQUE.mp3");` if your source folder is set as `source`folder

Comment: @MrT, this gives me Java.lang.NullPointerException. 

I used

String musicFileName = this.getClass().getResource("/bin/ROQUE.mp3").toString();

Comment: @DylanKidd is your source-folder set as source folder in the project within your IDE ?

Comment: @MrT Sure is. I am using eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone having trouble with this should check out this thread, initializing JavaFX from a separate method or class fixes this, I'm not sure I understand the ins and outs yet but it works for now!

[How to use JavaFX MediaPlayer correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490064/how-to-use-javafx-mediaplayer-correctly)