# Does Javafx mediaplayer/media object support remote files?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make a chatbot for livestreaming.  I am trying to add a song request feature that uses youtube.  I have tried to get it work with youtube and a google drive mp3 but both give MediaException: could not create media player.  It works using a file:/// address.
Code to access media

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Media media=new Media("http:///youtube.com/embed/n5O0iA--sec");
    if(media.getError()!=null){
        System.out.println("media error");
        media.getError().printStackTrace();
    }
    MediaPlayer player=new MediaPlayer(media);
    if(player.getError()!=null){
        System.out.println("player error");
        player.getError().printStackTrace();
    }
    player.setAutoPlay(true);
    player.setOnReady(new Runnable(){
        @Override public void run(){
            System.out.println("Video is ready");
        }
    });
    player.setOnError(new Runnable(){
        @Override public void run(){
            System.out.println("videoplayer errored");
            player.getError().printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    });
    player.play();
    MediaView mView=new MediaView();
    mView.setMediaPlayer(player);
    mView.setOnError(new EventHandler<MediaErrorEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(MediaErrorEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("view error");
            arg0.getMediaError().printStackTrace(System.out);;
        }
    });
    stage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(mView)));
    //view.getEngine().load(url);
    //stage.setScene(new Scene(view));
    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.show();
}
```

note:  I am using `javafx.application` to run the above code in a gui but the gui is not necessary.
Stacktrace:

```
 view error
MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not ?create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.access$1000(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer$InitMediaPlayer.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
videoplayer errored
MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create ?player!
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.access$1000(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer$InitMediaPlayer.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Please provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the video not playing.  The example you have provided is not complete (e.g. url is undefined).

Comment: @jewelsea sorry I forgot to include the declaration of the variable url but I have replaced it with the url string it represented as well inserted the stacktrace.

Comment: Youtube doesn't directly expose media files so mediaplayer is not going to work for that.

Comment: Additionally, I'm not sure it even supports mp3. It definitely supports http access to media but if you want to test it, point it to something like a publicly hosted aiff file like one of these http://www-eng-x.llnl.gov/documents/tests/aiff.html

Comment: @pvg it supports LOCAL mp3 files and aiff does load but it appears not REMOTE mp3 files or youtube links.

Comment: It's never going to support youtube links, I'm not sure why you thought it might. Remote mp3 or aiff is a bit different, though and you should check against something remote that's less convoluted than a google drive url. A server simply serving the file, without auth, without potential user agent checks, etc - i.e. something verifiable with curl.

Answer (score -1):

JavaFX `MediaPlayer` supports remote files via HTTP. Simply adapting the code from [How to use JavaFX MediaPlayer correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490064/how-to-use-javafx-mediaplayer-correctly) you can verify this with

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.media.*;

public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 200);

        Media pick = new Media("http://www-eng-x.llnl.gov/documents/a_sound.aiff");
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(pick);
        player.play();

        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(player);
        ((Group)scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(mediaView);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Media Player");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         launch(args);
    }
}
```

This brings up a window and plays the remote aiff without trouble.

Comment: Have you tried to make it work with google drive links like asked in the question?

Comment: @GuillaumeF. if you have a specific question, you should write that up and post it.