# trying to play an mp3 file in bluej and toolbox isn't initializing (on a mac)

Tags: java, javafx, mp3, bluej, toolbox

this is my code, its meant to play an mp3 file which I put in my bluej folder, im really stumped with the toolbox error though.

```
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
public class JavaAudioPlaySoundExample2
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   try {
   System.out.print("pls work");   
   String bip = "Mattashi8bit.mp3";
   Media hit = new Media(new File(bip).toURI().toURL().toString());
   MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
   mediaPlayer.play();
  } catch (Exception e) {

  }

  }

}
```

this is the full error

```
Exception in thread "Thread-29" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:273)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:268)
    at javafx.application.Platform.runLater(Platform.java:83)
    at javafx.scene.media.Media$_MetadataListener.onMetadata(Media.java:541)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.MetadataParserImpl.done(MetadataParserImpl.java:120)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.java.ID3MetadataParser.parse(ID3MetadataParser.java:237)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.MetadataParserImpl.run(MetadataParserImpl.java:103)
```

I would be really grateful if someone could fix me how to fix the code

Comment: is this android?

Comment: im just doing this on my mac (im pretty clueless lol)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490064/how-to-use-javafx-mediaplayer-correctly

Comment: it says my code is abstract so it can't override the start() method, when i make it an abstract class it still doesn't work